# Discrete random variable with unknown probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 10 boxes and there is a ball in one of them. The probability distribution is unknown. Is it possible to say that the probability of finding the ball in the box #1 is 1/10 or is this probability undefined because we know nothing about the probability distribution?

The question can be rephrased as follows:
if there is a discrete random variable which can take integer values from 1 to 10 and its probability distribution is not known, is it possible to calculate the probability of outcome 1?

Comment: It's not clear what such a statement might mean.  After all, the ball is either in box $1$ or it isn't, so the answer to the stated problem is either $0$ or $1$.  Now, if we understand something about the process we can estimate that value better.  But absent any such information, it isn't clear what any answer might mean.

Comment: lulu, of course when we check the box there are no more possibilities, the ball is either there or not. The question is about can we determine the probability of the ball being in the given box or not. E.g. if the probability distribution is uniform we can tell that this probability is 1/10.

Comment: But what does it mean to "determine the probability"?  This is a one shot trial...there is no (natural) probability attached.  And yes, if you specify that the ball was placed according to a draw from a specified distribution, then that's what the probability means.  But are you specifying that?

Comment: People model real situations with probability, but it frequently fails or at least falls far short.  You might say something like "ask everyone in the world to place a ball in one of $10$ boxes according to whatever method they favor". Then your question would have a numerically defined answer which I strongly suspect would not be $.1$ as (my guess) is that people would all think it was "more random" to avoid the edge boxes.  Human versions of random processes aren't random at all.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, the question is, can we say something about the probability with such little data as I stated. If you tell that it's not possible to tell anything about the probability in this situation, ok, it can be the answer. The same is correct about the second (rephrased) question, isn't it?

Comment: I would say that it was.  One problem, abstractly, is that there isn't a natural measure on the "space of probability distributions".  If there were such a thing, you could argue that (in your case) it would probably give the symmetric answer.  What else could it possibly give?  But I would say that the better answer is that the problem is ill-posed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a textbook motivation for something like Markov's Inequality:

For any non-negative Random Variable $X$ with mean $\mu < \infty$, we have that **P**$(X > k\mu) \leq 1/k$ for any $k>0 $.

Although this isn't precisely the answer to your question, it is situations like this (when we only know partial information about the distribution instead of having an analytical expression) that serves as one motivation for probability inequalities.